# How to import or insert contacts from .vcf file in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-contacts, vcf-vcard

I create `.vcf` file of all contacts in Android using below code.

```
public static void getVCF() 
{
    final String vfile = "POContactsRestore.vcf";
    Cursor phones = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null, null);
    phones.moveToFirst();
    for(int i =0;i<phones.getCount();i++)
    {
         String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
         Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
         AssetFileDescriptor fd;
         try 
         {
             fd = mContext.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
             FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
             byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
             fis.read(buf);
             String VCard = new String(buf);
             String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + vfile;
             FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path, true);
                        mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());           
             phones.moveToNext();                           
             Log.d("Vcard",  VCard);
         } 
         catch (Exception e1) 
         {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e1.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
}
```

How to add / restore  contacts from `.vcf` file  programatically in Android?

I want to restore all contacts form that `.vcf` file in to Android using code.
How to do this?

Answer (score 11):

Actually I also want to do the same and a after a long research finally i got the solution.

Here is the piece of code to restore:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(storage_path+vfile)),"text/x-vcard"); //storage path is path of your vcf file and vFile is name of that file.
startActivity(intent);
```

Enjoy!!

Comment: +1 for the working stuff, but think this doesn't answer the question. I think the question refers to how to programmatically do it and not using external apps that handle the vcard.

Comment: Also, I think the question is how to use the CONTENT_VCARD_URI when importing a vcard - not just export.

Comment: @pyus13 how to stop importing duplicate contacts. Is there any <type> or <extra> which we can pass to achieve the goal.

Comment: Jus want to say THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH ! :D

Comment: @FernandoBonet Its great that it helped you.