# how to restore contacts from vcf file with my own code

Tags: android

I am abel to take backup of all the phone contacts into a vcf file by writing my own code. but how to restore contacts from a vcf file to the android phone with my own code. is there any way to not to use the android activity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596608/how-to-import-or-insert-contacts-from-vcf-file-in-android-programatically

Comment: hey i visited the link but i dint find any code to restore or import contacts. plz help