# How to read and restore contact in device from vcf contact file + android

Tags: android, contacts, vcf-vcard

I have try  to restore contact from vcf file using default system Contact/people application of phone.

[How to import or insert contacts from .vcf file in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596608/how-to-import-or-insert-contacts-from-vcf-file-in-android-programmatically)

but it opens Dialog button action using where i can see different Install application which can read VCF file. but i dont what that dialog. i want to restore it using default system Contact/People application.

is there any unique package for that application? So that i can use it?

i have also check
 [How to import contacts from VCF file by using code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696873/how-to-import-contacts-from-vcf-file-by-using-code/)

but it not says where to start like not info about VCF load etc

Please help me to find out solution of my problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import or insert contacts from .vcf file in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596608/how-to-import-or-insert-contacts-from-vcf-file-in-android-programmatically)